# Непонятны некоторые параметры модели Маркова в пакете HiddenMarkov в R

Tags: r

Пример из пакета HiddenMarkov

```
library("HiddenMarkov") #включили пакет
Pi <- matrix(c(1/2, 1/2, 0, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 0, 1/2, 1/2), byrow=TRUE, nrow=3)
```

Pi - m*m - матрица, вероятность перехода однородной скрытой марковской цепи

```
delta <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

delta - это краевое распределение вероятности m скрытых состояний в (первой временной точке) - дословный перевод

```
lambda <- c(1, 4, 2, 5, 3)
```

lambda - параметры модели

```
m <- nrow(Pi)
x <- dthmm(NULL, Pi, delta, "pois", list(lambda=lambda), discrete=TRUE)
```

создаем скрытую Марковскую цепь (объект класса dthmm)

```
x <- simulate(x, nsim=2000)
```

симулируем дату рандомных значений

------ Global Decoding ------

```
states <- Viterbi(x)
```

определяем состояния модели

```
states <- factor(states, levels=1:m)
```

количество состояний ???
Compare predicted states with true states

```
p[j,k] = Pr{Viterbi predicts state k | true state is j}
p <- matrix(NA, nrow=m, ncol=m)
for (j in 1:m){
a <- (x$y==j)
p[j,] <- table(states[a])/sum(a)
}
print(p)
```

Сравниваем и отбираем правильные состояния

Собственно вопросы:

Как отбираются параметры модели Lambda?
Что такое delta, зачем она нужна и как задаются параметры?
Как обращаться к параметрам модели и оценивать качество?
Как потом запустить модель на тестовой выборке?

Очень прошу совета. Спасибо